# Show that this series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to show that the following series converges.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n/2}\sqrt{\log{(2^n)}}$$

I tried to bound it from above by a convergent sequence without success. It would be appreciated if someone could help me. Thanks four your help.

hulik

Comment: As an aside, it converges to $\sqrt{\log(2)}\mathrm{Li}_{\frac{-1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, where $\mathrm{Li}$ is the polylogarithm.

Answer (score 3):

$\log(2^n) = n \log (2)$, so we consider $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2^{n/2}}$. But any polynomial over an exponential converges, right?

Comment: How do you show $\sum \frac{n^k}{l^n}$ for every $k,l> 0$?

Comment: I think we also need $l>1$.  Then the ratio test works.

Comment: @hulik: I only just now checked. The ratio test works, as Patrick mentioned. It is also clearly false if $l < 1$, as then the limit of the terms isn't even $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\log(2^n) = n \log(2)$.  So, in your series, the $\sqrt{\log 2}$ is a constant that can be pulled out, i.e., it does not affect convergence or divergence.  What you're left with is
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2^{n/2}}$$
Does that seem easier?  Use the ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned the comparison test... First notice that
$$2^{-n/2}\sqrt{\log{(2^n)}} = \frac{\sqrt{n\log{(2)}}}{\sqrt{2^n}} = \sqrt{\frac{n\log(2)}{2^n}},$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n/2}\sqrt{\log{(2^n)}} = \sqrt{\log(2)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{n}{2^n}}.$$
Next, notice that $2^{n/2}\geq n$ for any $n\geq 4$. Hence:
$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty 2^{-n/2}\sqrt{\log{(2^n)}} = \sqrt{\log(2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{n}{2^n}} \leq  \sqrt{\log(2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{2^{n/2}}{2^{n}}} = \sqrt{\log(2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}}=\sqrt{\log(2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n/4}},$$
and the last series is clearly convergent! Thus, the original series is convergent as well.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test or root test will do this very nicely.